# Browser compatibility issue with css and html

Tags: html, css, browser, compatibility, navbar

I have icons to different sites that become smaller if you put your mouse on them. On firefox the icons becoming smaller don't have an impact on the navbar but on all other browsers it does.
This is how it looks like on Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

And this is how it looks like on Microsoft Edge, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera:
[image: Other browsers]

Code(CSS):

```
/* Navbar Section */
#navbar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
/* End Of Navbar Section */
/* Website Icons Section */
#youtube {
    margin-top: 120px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#youtube:hover {
    width: 40px;
    height: 29px;
}
#twitch {
    margin-top: 113px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#twitch:hover {
    width: 40px;
    height: 41px;
}
#facebook {
    margin-top: 116px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#facebook:hover {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
#twitter {
    margin-top: 116px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#twitter:hover {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
#googlePlus {
    margin-top: 117px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#googlePlus:hover {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
#patreon {
    margin-top: 118px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
#patreon:hover {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
/* End Of Website Icons Section */
/* Link Section */
.nFx {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* End Of Link Section */
```

Code(HTML):

```
<a class="nFx" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/" alt="Watch my videos" target="new">
<img id="youtube" align="right" src="images/YouTube-Icon.png" width="50" height="36" alt="Watch my videos"/>
</a>
<a class="nFx" href="http://www.twitch.tv/" alt="Watch my streams" target="new">
<img id="twitch" align="right" src="images/Twitch-Icon.png" width="50" height="51" alt="Watch my streams"/>
</a>
<a class="nFx" href="https://www.facebook.com/" alt="Follow me on Facebook" target="new">
<img id="facebook" align="right" src="images/Facebook-Icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Follow me on Facebook"/>
</a>
<a class="nFx" href="https://twitter.com/" alt="Follow me on Twitter" target="new">
<img id="twitter" align="right" src="images/Twitter-Icon.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Follow me on Twitter"/>
</a>
<a class="nFx" href="https://plus.google.com/" alt="Follow me on Google+" target="new">
<img id="googlePlus" align="right" src="images/GooglePlus-Icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Follow me on Google+"/>
</a>
<a class="nFx" href="https://www.patreon.com/" alt="Support me on Patreon" target="new">
<img id="patreon" align="right" src="images/Patreon-Icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Support me on Patreon"/>
</a>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a class="activeNavA" href="#">Active Navbar Element</a></li>
<li><a class="navA" href="#">Navbar Element</a></li>
<li><a class="navA" href="#">Navbar Element</a></li>
<li><a class="navA" href="#">Navbar Element</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce on codepen. It looks like you may need to apply a clearfix. Also you may want to use something else than align-right on the images.

Comment: I was just wondering what is making the icons align to the right...

Comment: A couple more hints: don't use one id per image but a class, you will be able to apply the code in one css handler to manage all of them.

Comment: Here is a link to jsfiddle(equivalent of codepen), but it looks messed up without the pictures: http://jsfiddle.net/34rnfvy1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a clearfix after your list of icons:

```
<div style="clear:both">

</div>
```

This should avoid the floaty menu.

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1pm5uz28/

Comment: That worked pretty well, there's only minimal up movement when hovering over the twitter icon.

Comment: @Jojo01 Yes but that's because in the fiddle there are no icons but just text maybe? Does the vertical movement happen also in your page with the real icons?

Comment: It doesn't happen on Firefox tho

Comment: @Jojo01 Thats because the icon has a different size: set also twitter to 40 px <img id="twitter" align="right" src="images/Twitter-Icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Follow me on Twitter"/>

Comment: @Jojo01 and you should also change the hover width and height in the css code (maybe set everything to 30px)